# Reindex command line for specific store view

Tags: magento-1.9, reindex, command-line

I'm wondering is there any way to re-index the "Catalog Url Rewrites" of a specific store view in Magento with Multiple Stores. Is it possible to have store Id in `indexer.php` command-line?

Answer (score 1):

Indexing all "Catalog Url Rewrites" This is not possible out of the box. Magento supports two ways of indexing One product/item or all for command line. you can check the `indexer.php` for more detail. Instead you can try the `plainReindex($products = null, $attributes = null, $stores = null)` function from the `catalogindex/indexer` like this along with store id:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalogindex/indexer')->plainReindex(null, null, $store);
```

Hope this will help you.